# ask the user to type an integer and then prints "Yes" if that integer is divisible by 3, otherwise prints "No" (Python)

Tags: python, input, integer

I am new to Python. I have learned the If else statement, sto this exercise has to be with the If else and not with something more.

> Write a program which asks the user to type an integer and then prints "Yes" if that integer is divisible by 3, otherwise prints "No"

My code is this:

```
user_input = input("Type an integer: ")
user_int = int(user_input)
if user_int / 3:
    print("Yes)
else:
    print("No")
```

I think I messed up the `if` statement, but really I cannot figure it out.

Comment: `print("Yes)` should be replaced with `print("Yes")` and also have a look at the answer below to get the correct algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
user_input = input("Type an integer: ")
user_int = int(user_input)
if user_int % 3==0:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

1. `print("Yes")`
2. Use modulo operator

Answer (score 1):

`n` is divisible by `k` if the modulo is zero. So, your condition should be `if user_number % 3 == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `print("Yes")` instead of `print("Yes)`